# Is there a way to make a loop that executes before the frame is rendered?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script in my Unity game that rotates and moves the VR player's camera. Currently, I have the code running in an update loop but the update loop runs during the frame (I assume). This makes the camera feel like it moves late and can be really disorienting.

Is there a way to execute my code before the frame is drawn?

```
private void Update() {
    head.localPosition = VRInputHandler.HeadsetPosition;
    head.localRotation = VRInputHandler.HeadsetRotation;
}
```

Comment: Based on [`the execution order`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html), `Update` happens before `Scene Rendering`. You will want to place camera operations in `LateUpdate`, after the scene is done rendering.

Answer (score 2):

After much digging around, I found a solution that looks to work well. It's as simple as subscribing to an event called "onAfterUpdate".

I'll paste the code that worked for me below:

```
private void OnEnable() {
    InputSystem.onAfterUpdate += EarlyUpdate;
}
    
private void OnDisable() {
    InputSystem.onAfterUpdate -= EarlyUpdate;
}

private void EarlyUpdate() {
    head.localPosition = VRInputHandler.HeadsetPosition;
    head.localRotation = VRInputHandler.HeadsetRotation;
}
```

Note: I don't think this event was designed to do this but it works.

Comment: I wonder how many performance issues and bugs in well established game engines come from people saying "I don't think ____ was designed for this, but it works".